# EF core stored procedure : getting 'No best type found for implicitly-typed array' error while posting multiple parameters

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, entity-framework-core

I try using stored procedures with EF core. My purpose is that getting rows count from database table, but I can't send multiple parameters. I am getting an error:

> No best type found for implicitly-typed array

Actually I don't know how to use Linq syntax. Thanks in advance

Stored procedure:

```
create proc sp_getExistorNExistCountStd 
    @Date datetime2(7),
    @ClassId int,
    @Absent bit,
    @Count int out
as
begin
    select @Count = COUNT(*) 
    from RollCalls
    where DateRollCall = @Date 
      and ClassId = @ClassId 
      and [Absent] = @Absent

    return @Count
end
```

C#

```
int ExistStdCount = db.RollCalls.FromSql("sp_getExistorNExistCountStd @p0 ,@p1, @p2",
                       // getting error in this section
                       parameters: new[] {DateTime.Now.Date, classIds[i], true }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Use `new object[] { ... }` instead.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find the solution to count rows using output parameter but I reached another solution.. This method gave me what I wanted

```
Create proc [dbo].[sp_getExistorNExistCountStd] 
    @Date datetime2(7),
    @ClassId int,
    @Absent bit     
    as
    begin

        select Id from RollCalls
        where DateRollCall=@Date 
        and ClassId=@ClassId 
        and [Absent]=@Absent
    end
```

---

```
 int ExistStdCount = db.RollCalls.FromSql("sp_getExistorNExistCountStd @p0 ,@p1, @p2",
             DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("yyyyMMdd"), classIds[i], 0).ToList().Count();
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do You use stored procedure?
The EF generates sql really smart. Did You tried: `db.RollCalls.Where(rc => DateTime.Now.Date.Equals(rc.DateRollCall)/* && other conditions */).Count()`

Comment: yes I knew to get count by thids method but I wanted to use stored procedure (especially with out parameter) to see difference between two method in terms of performance.